# TLS failedtoverifycertificate: X509:certificate is valid for*.search.windows.net,*.management.search.windows.net not containerreg.acr.io

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

I am trying to connect to **`ACR registry`** using ***private endpoint from ADO pipeline*** , But getting the error below:-

```
ERROR: Get "https://containerreg.acr.io/v2/": net/http: TLS failed to verify certificate: X509: certificate is valid for  _.search.windows.net,_.management.search.windows.net not containerreg.acr.io
```

But When changing it to **`public access network`** we are able to **access acr and push and pull the images.**

- Created **`private endpoint in vnetA`.**
- Created virtual network link in **`Private DNS Zone`** as our **`Devops agent is in VNETB`** still we are getting tls/ssl certificate issue.

Comment: You need to place your DevOps agent in the same VNET as your private endpoint, As DevOps agent is in VNETB, In Azure there's no internal connection between two separate VNETS, You will need to create VNET peering between VnetA and VnetB for this connection to work, Or place devops agent in the same VNETA, As resources inside same VNET can communicate with each other.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering?tabs=peering-portal > Refer this Document for VNET Peering

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Ms document for implementing ACR with private endpoint and accessing it via Azure Devops pipeline using self hosted agents.

> - Once the public network access is disabled, instances of certain Azure services including Azure DevOps Services are currently unable to access the container registry.
> - Private endpoints are not currently supported with Azure DevOps managed agents. You will need to use a self-hosted agent with network line of sight to the private endpoint.

You need to place your DevOps agent in the same VNET as your private endpoint, As DevOps agent is in VNETB, In Azure there's no internal connection between two separate VNETS, You will need to create VNET peering between VnetA and VnetB for this connection to work, Or place devops agent in the same VNETA, As resources inside same VNET can communicate with each other.

Or you need to add your VNETB as a private-endpoint in the ACR.

1. I have created one ACR enabled private endpoint.
   [image]
2. Then I referred this MS Document [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-vnet#create-a-docker-enabled-virtual-machine) , To create a VM> and Enable access to this VM with private ACR.
3. Created one VM in the same VNET as my ACR.
4. Enabled ACR service endpoint on Vm's subnet.
5. Added this subnet as in ACR.
6. Added VM's subnet as a private endpoint in the ACR.
7. Enabled this VM as a self hosted agent for Azure Devops.
8. ried accessing the ACR from VM and it was successful.

I enabled `Microsoft.ContainerRegistry` service endpoint on my VM's subnet:-

```bash
az network vnet subnet update --name default --vnet-name silicon-vnet --resource-group siliconacr-rg --service-endpoints Microsoft.ContainerRegistry
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Add a network rule in ACR to allow this Vm's subnet to access ACR:-

```bash
az acr network-rule add --name valleyacr --subnet /subscriptions/0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconacr-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/silicon-vnet/subnets/default
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Add this VM as a `self hosted agent` in your ***Azure DevOps pipeline***:-

[image]